# Pass alert value into input field

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have a function that alerts my current longitude and latitude.
However, I do not want to alert this value.
Instead, I want this value to be input into the *Location Textbox* upon clicking "Pan"

```
<html>    
<script>
    function getPosition() {
        var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            maximumAge: 3600000
        }

        var watchID = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

        function onSuccess(position) {
            alert('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' +
                  'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '\n');
        };

        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br> 

    <label for="Location">Location:</label>
    <button onclick = "getPosition()" id = "getPosition">PAN</button>
    <input type="text" name="Location" id="location">
    <br>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your success function, you should set the value of the location input textbox, rather than doing an alert

```
function onSuccess(position) {
    var input = document.getElementById('location');

    input.value = position.coords.latitude + ', ' + position.coords.longitude;
}
```